# How to include an html file within html

Tags: html

I am trying to put a footer.htm in my index.htm file but i am not able so far. Here is my code.

index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is my index page!</p>
<!--#include virtual="footer.htm" -->

<!--#include file="footer.htm" -->

</body>
</html>
```

footer.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is my footer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried it within visual studio 2010 builtin web server and i also tried through apache but no luck whatsoever.Please note that i am trying it in html5

Comment: No, you're not "trying it in HTML 5."  Your `DOCTYPE` is for XHTML 1.0 Transitional, not HTML 5.

Comment: if include is the case for, you want to show your footer.htm in index.htm, iframe will do this work for you, place `<iframe src="footer.htm" > </iframe>` in index.htm

Comment: i might not be using html5 but the target is schema is html5 .. also with your solution i can uses iframe for the purpose .. what you suggest? i want to include footer and header on every page ... should i go with iframe or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You are using [server side include](http://bignosebird.com/ssi.shtml) syntax. You need to configure your webserver to process your HTML document for SSI directives.

There is a [guide to configuring SSI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html) in the Apache manual.

Comment: thanks for ssi supposittion ... will this work in every browser?

Comment: A supposition is "an uncertain belief". There is nothing uncertain about my answer. Server side includes are a server side technology. Because they are implemented by the server, the browser is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax looks correct for SSIs. Maybe you should check:

That SSIs are supported on your webhost
That the filename is correct (i.e. htm and not html.)